# Show 12 days before Date as Current date

Tags: java, calendar

I have made a custom Calendar.It shows the device's date as current date. But my requirement is to show 12 days before Date as current date. e.g-Today is 21 but I want my calendar to show 9. I want to do the same with year also. 
I know how to get the current date. I am using this code.

```
_calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
month = _calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
year = _calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
Log.d(tag, "Calendar Instance:= " + "Month: " + month + " " + "Year: " + year);
```

My new code is

```
_calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
month = _calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
year = _calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
Log.d(tag, "Calendar Instance:= " + "Month: " + month + " " + "Year: " + year);
/*_calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -12);*/
_calendar.roll(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -12);
_calendar.roll(Calendar.MONTH, -12);
Calendar _calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
_calendar.roll(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -12);
_calendar.roll(Calendar.YEAR, -12);
```

This will [roll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#roll%28int,%20int%29) back the days by 12, and then the year by 12.

Comment: @Prinkal you're logging the month and day before you `roll`, so perhaps you just think it isn't working? Or do you think it's not working for some other reason?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26600/discussion-between-prinkal-and-tushar)

Answer (score 0):

In many languages `NOW` is a function that returns a `DateTime` of the time when called. You can `add` a negative (-) number of days to it and it will return what you need. I always forget that, thinking you can only add a positive, but that's not correct. ;-)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
_calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
_calendar.setTime(new Date());
_calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -12);
Date twelveDaysAgo = _calendar.getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

This will move the date back by 12 days, will change month/year as well if needed.

```
_calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -12);
```